# Javascript onfocusin event only in inputs

Tags: javascript

i have a simple code with a `form` with `onfocusin`. This event is called when i focus `input`, and this is right. But the event is called too when i press `button`. How can i tell javascript to ignore this `onfocusin` event to `buttons`?

Example below:

```html
<form onfocusin="console.log('Input received Focus')">
      <input placeholder="name"/><br>
      <input placeholder="age"/><br>
      <input placeholder="full name"/><br>
      <button type="button">Send!</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can’t tell it to ignore the event itself - but you can check the event target inside your handler function (go read up on that), and then based on that decide whether you want to do anything further, or just quit it at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the button element , using the event target..

```js
function focusFunction(e){
  if(e.target.tagName != 'BUTTON'){
    console.log('Input received Focus')
  } 
}
```

```html
<form onfocusin="focusFunction(event)">
      <input placeholder="name"/><br>
      <input placeholder="age"/><br>
      <input placeholder="full name"/><br>
      <button type="button">Send!</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This answer is the most cleaner that i have seen. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form>
    <input placeholder="name" />
    <br>
    <input placeholder="age" />
    <br>
    <input placeholder="full name" />
    <br>
    <button type="button">Send!</button>
</form>
<script>
    const $inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form > input');
    $inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('focus', () => console.log('Input received Focus')))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give input field to `onfocusin` event

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="name" onfocusin="console.log('Input received Focus')" /><br>
  <input placeholder="age" onfocusin="console.log('Input received Focus')"/><br>
  <input placeholder="full name" onfocusin="console.log('Input received Focus')"/><br>
  <button type="button">Send!</button>
</form>
```

Or make function for this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body> 
<form>
      <input placeholder="name" onfocusin="myFunc()" /><br>
      <input placeholder="age" onfocusin="myFunc()"/><br>
      <input placeholder="full name" onfocusin="myFunc()"/><br>
      <button type="button">Send!</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(){
        console.log('Input received Focus');
    }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, but if i have 50 inputs, it will be hard to maintain this code. =/